# how to make buttons float over an image on mouse over in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have an image gallery in ReactJS using bootstrap. I want to add buttons to delete or further modify the images. These buttons should only appear in the corner of the image when the mouse is over the respective image.
I've been looking far and wide and either I just don't know the right terms as to what this is called or it is not as common as I thought.
Of course if the same question already answered exists I'd be more than thankful to be pointed to said question.

Comment: Have you made an attempt at doing this on your own?

Comment: I don't exactly know where to start. I am not sure which is the best practice to place components on top of each other using bootstrap

Comment: I was considering using the z-index css property but that feels very hacky in this environment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something you might start with (based on one image):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Image, Button } from "react-bootstrap";

const ImageExample = () => {
  const [isHovered, setHover] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div
      className="imageContainer"
      onMouseOver={() => setHover(true)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setHover(false)}
    >
      <Image src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"/>
      {isHovered && (
        <Button
          size="sm"
          style={{
            position: "absolute",
            top: "5px",
            right: "5px",
          }}
          variant="primary"
        >
          Show on hover
        </Button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ImageExample;
```

```
.imageContainer {
  max-width: 150px;
  max-height: 150px;
  position: relative;
}
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-wilbur-qugei